# How to include only one contrast of a 3+ level categorical predictor into the random effect structure of a lmer model?

Tags: r, regression, lme4, mixed-models

Some of the mixed models I've run in the past have had categorical predictors with more than two levels.  When I include such variables into the random effect structure of a `lmer()` model, I've obtained results that suggest there is a random effect of one contrast (or comparison) but there is no random effect of the remaining contrasts.

**My main question is**: How, if possible, could I specify only one contrast to include as a random effect with a categorical predictor that has 3 or more levels?

**An example**: Say I've collected data on 20 individuals, where they each went through 3 conditions (A, B, C).  I know from previous work that the effect of going from condition A to condition B is fixed (no randomness), but I want to include a random effect for going from condition A to C.

```
df <- data.frame(PID = rep(1:20, 10), group = rep(c("A", "B", "C"),200), y = rnorm(200))

model <- lmer(y ~ group + (1 + group | PID),
              data = df,
              REML = TRUE)

#Partial summary
summary(model)
Random effects:
 Groups   Name        Variance  Std.Dev.  Corr     
 PID      (Intercept) 6.298e-02 0.2509490          
          groupB      1.907e-08 0.0001381 0.91     
          groupC      4.423e-08 0.0002103 0.75 0.96
 Residual             9.007e-01 0.9490689
```

As can be seen above, including `group` as a random effect leads to two random effects.  One for the comparison between group A to group B, and another for the comparison between group B to group C. Is there a way to specify only the comparison between group A to group C in the random effect syntax?

Comment: The contrasts in R are by default treatment contrasts, so your understanding is wrong about the comparisons being made. The groupC result above is in fact what you are requesting.

Comment: Expanding on @42's comment. From the output you are missing `groupA`. This is due to the fact that this is the "contrast baseline" that is chosen when using the factor in the model. Thus `groupB` and `groupC` is the comparison between this "baseline" and the alternative group. Thus `groupC` is the comparison between the baseline `groupA` and the specific group `groupC`.

Comment: I understand that R will include the comparisons of A vs. B and A vs. C by default.  What I'm asking is how to tell R to only include the treatment contrast of A vs. C in the random effect structure.

Comment: I forgot to check up on this question again. @gp_R, The question then becomes, how the model should include the remaining data? The most obvious way to make the model only include the comparison is to take a subset (i believe `lmer(...., subset = group != "B")` works), but it seems you are looking to include **all** the data. How should the B group be handled? It cant be handled as missing a random effect group, so is it an `A` or `C` group? I hope you see the conundrum.